Linker error, can't compile GLFW on MacOS
I'm trying to setup my project using premake but i'm getting some linking error with GLFW, here are the premake files:
premake file for GLFW lib:
project "GLFW"
    kind "StaticLib"
    language "C"

    targetdir ("%{wks.location}/bin/%{cfg.platform}_%{cfg.buildcfg}/%{prj.name}")
    objdir ("%{wks.location}/bin-int/%{cfg.platform}_%{cfg.buildcfg}/%{prj.name}")

    -- support only for MacOS

    files {
        "include/GLFW/glfw3.h",
        "include/GLFW/glfw3native.h",
        "src/glfw_config.h",
        "src/context.c",
        "src/init.c",
        "src/input.c",
        "src/monitor.c",
        "src/vulkan.c",
        "src/window.c",
        "src/egl_context.c",
        "src/osmesa_context.c",
        "src/cocoa_time.c",
        "src/posix_module.c",
        "src/posix_thread.c",
        "src/cocoa_init.m",
        "src/cocoa_joystick.m",
        "src/cocoa_monitor.m",
        "src/cocoa_window.m",
        "src/nsgl_context.m"
    }

    defines {
        "_GLFW_COCOA"
    }

premake file for workspace and project:
workspace "GLFWWindowWorkspace"
    architecture "ARM64"

    configurations {
        "Debug",
        "Release"
    }

    IncludeDir = {}
    IncludeDir["glfw"] = "%{wks.location}/vendor/GLFW/include"

    group "Dependencies"
        include "vendor/GLFW"

    group "Core"
        project "GLFWWindow"
        kind "ConsoleApp"
        language "C++"
        cppdialect "C++20"

        targetdir ("%{wks.location}/bin/%{cfg.platform}_%{cfg.buildcfg}/%{prj.name}")
        objdir ("%{wks.location}/bin-int/%{cfg.platform}_%{cfg.buildcfg}/%{prj.name}")

        files {
            "src/**.h",
            "src/**.hpp",
            "src/**.cpp"
        }

        includedirs {
            "%{IncludeDir.glfw}"
        }
      
        links {
            "OpenGL.framework",
            "Cocoa.framework",
            "IOKit.framework",
            "CoreFoundation.framework",
            "GLFW"
        }

and the linker error message:
`ld: Undefined symbols:`
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_CAMetalLayer, referenced from:
       in libGLFW.a[6](cocoa_window.o)
  __glfwSelectPlatform, referenced from:
      _glfwInit in libGLFW.a[9](init.o)

Does anyone know how can i solve this issue.

GLFW is built with cmake. With that said, there is a manual compilation section down at the bottom of that page, but those instructions are incredibly sparse. My vote in these situations is always to utilize a package manager in your projects. This is not what you should be concerned about, but the actual writing of code.

links order is important with some compiler, try to put "GLFW" before openGL.
